# Java: Same string returns different byte arrays

Tags: java, string, byte

I would expect the byte representation of two identical strings to also be identical yet this does not seem to be the case. Below is the code I've used to test this.

```
    String test1 = "125";
    String test2 = test1;

    if(test1.equals(test2))
    {
        System.out.println("These strings are the same");
    }

    byte[] array1 = test1.getBytes();
    byte[] array2 = test2.getBytes();

    if(array1.equals(array2))
    {
        System.out.println("These bytes are the same");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Bytes are not the same:\n" + array1 + " " + array2);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Look into character encodings.

Comment: Oh, you're using the `equals` method incorrectly with array types.

Comment: The problem here is nothing to do with Unicode, or character encodings.  That's all a red herring.  It's simply that `equals` for array objects does the same thing as `==`.  Any answer that talks about character encodings is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Byte representations of two identical but unrelated `String` objects would most certainly be identical byte-for-byte. However, they would not be *the same* array object, as long as the `String` objects are unrelated.

Your code is checking array equality incorrectly. Here is how you can fix it:

```
if(Arrays.equals(array1, array2)) ...
```

Moreover, you would get different byte arrays even if you call `getBytes` on the same `String` object multiple times:

```
String test = "test";
byte[] a = test.getBytes();
byte[] b = test.getBytes();
if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("same");
} else {
    System.out.println("different");
}
```

[The above code prints `"different"`.](http://ideone.com/XA77p1)

This is because the `String` does not persist the results of `getBytes`.

Note: your code does call `getBytes` on the same object twice, because this line

```
String test2 = test1;
```

does not copy the string, but creates a second reference to the same string object.

Comment: I'm feeling a little silly for making the comparison mistake. Can you explain a little further as to why the same string wouldn't have the same byte representation? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3557692 The code that produces the byte representation creates a new `byte[]` array, fills it in, and returns it to the caller. It does not save a copy for the next time a user might request that array, so in subsequent calls it starts by creating a new array instance. Both arrays would be filled with the same bytes, but they would be different array objects.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `array1.equals(array2)` is not doing what you think it does; it returns equivalent but not reference-identical arrays.  If you used `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)`, it would have worked.

Comment: +1 you need to compare the contents of the `byte[]` not the references themselves.

Answer (score 1):

getBytes() returns different value every time we call on any object so we will get different values when we call like below

```
System.out.println("1 test1.getBytes() "+test1.getBytes());
 System.out.println("2 test2.getBytes() "+test2.getBytes());
```

both the values are different and storing in a byte[] array1 and byte[] array2 respectively,
since both are different bytes , 2 new byte array got created and hence their comparison with equals method compares the references and returns false.

so use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` this to compare the actual content in those 2 byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Some more explanation about `equals`:

The `equals` method in `Object` is the same as `==`; that is, it compares two references to see if they're equal.

However, `equals` is *overridden* in the `String` class, so that `equals` on two strings compares the contents of the strings, instead of the references.  That's why you need to use `equals` when comparing `String`s, instead of `==`.  Many other classes in the Java runtime also override `equals`, so that they do something other than comparing references.

Array classes (the "class" to which array objects belong), however, do **not** override `equals`.  I think the main reason is that there's no named array class in which an overriding `equals` could appear.  Thus, the idea of using `equals` to compare the contents, which works for `String`s, doesn't work for arrays.  The result is that, for an array `x`, `x.equals(y)` is the same as `x == y` (if `x` isn't `null`).  It uses the inherited `equals` from `Object`.

That's why the `Arrays` class is provided: to give you some of the methods that can't be provided because there's no class to put them in.  `Arrays.equals` and `Arrays.toString` are two such methods that you'd use instead of `x.equals` or `x.toString`.